# Разбор даты из строки с использованием SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android, java

Помогите найти ошибку в шаблоне для разбора строки.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
Date mDate = format.parse("Sat, 08 Feb 2014 14:01:00 PST");
```

На последней строчке вылетает: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat, 08 Feb 2014 14:01:00 PST"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861642/date-format-parse-exception-eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-z-yyyy
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979270/convert-a-timestamp-eee-d-mmm-yyyy-hhmmss-gmt-format-to-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss

Comment: Добавил локаль, теперь все работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @tch74 отметьте плиз ответ как правильный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить локаль. Например

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US)
```